# How to prevent vite/rollup from changing up index.html script paths?

Tags: javascript, html, vite, rollup

I have a relative script tag inside my `<head>` like this:

```html
<script type="module" src="/../modules/module1"></script>
```

It is marked as being external via the vite/rollup config. During build, it is moved into the bundle and the path is adjusted based on the file system of the build agent (e.g. `import "./modules/module1"`). However, the path is obviously not relative to the file system but the URL.

I tried a lot but I can't prevent the build from messing with that script tag or make vite/rollup understand that it's not relative to the current file system.

#### Reproduction

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-gvcugb?file=index.html

Run `npm i && npm run build`, check `dist/index.html` and the first chars in `dist/assets/index.*.js` and see the relative path has been moved and altered.

Comment: Is that path `/../modules/module1` ?

Comment: Do you have a `<base>` tag?  You can give reference as per that base tag

Comment: "Is that path /../modules/module1 ?" What path? "Do you have a <base> tag?" No, would that help?

Comment: Can you also attach a **minimal** reproducible [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) link which will help us debug the issue and playaround with the code?

Comment: @vighnesh153 I added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is apparently part of Vite:
[https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/vite/src/node/plugins/html.ts#L370](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/7d24b5f56697f6ec6e6facbe8601d3f993b764c8/packages/vite/src/node/plugins/html.ts#L370)

There it is marked for removal and file path resolution b/c the [`isExcluded`](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/7d24b5f56697f6ec6e6facbe8601d3f993b764c8/packages/vite/src/node/plugins/html.ts#L289) does not query `config.build.rollupOptions.external`.

I created an issue to hopefully address this problem: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/11017